# How do I know who sent a WAMP message?

Tags: autobahn, wamp-protocol, crossbar

Is there any way to get metadata about who (`authid`) published a given message or called an RPC? After I have users authenticate and authorize them for a given role (e.g. allowing them to publish to `mychat`) how can I prevent clients from spoofing each other's names? Subscribers/callees are just passed the arguments that the pub/caller passed; I don't see how to get session data.

A workaround might be to use [dynamic authorization](http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization/#dynamic-authorization), where each client is only authorized to publish to `mychat.<userid>`, but that seems icky. Can I just get the `session` dictionary for normal subs/calls like the dynamic authorization call gets?

Comment: Maybe like something from [here](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/rpc/options/backend.py) with `RegisterOptions`, `{disclose_me: true}`.... Need to check.

Answer (score 1):

This is done via the [publisher disclosure](http://crossbar.io/docs/Publisher-Identification/) and [caller disclosure](http://crossbar.io/docs/Caller-Identification/). This currently only sends you a sessionID, and you need to get the other data about the session via a [session meta call](http://crossbar.io/docs/Session-Metaevents-and-Procedures/). The sessionID is sent by the router, so cannot be spoofed by a client.